# C# convert from unicode using a different input variable type

Tags: c#, unicode

I am programming a messaging app that converts strings to and from unicode in order to later encrypt those strings.
Example from my code:

```
g = g + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Convert.ToInt32(d));
```

This line works just fine but it only supports int 32 as input variables. And that's a problem as in some occasions depending on user input the conversion to int32 will fail due to size limitations of int32.
One solution I see is to limit user input, but that would compromise message security which I would rather avoid.

Any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Comment: there are roughly a million unicode chars. Why do you need a variable larger than two billions (int32)?

Comment: Fair point, this comment made me realise that something must be wrong earlier in my code. Fixed the issue and now the problem doesn't appear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The method [Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.convertfromutf32) does not convert *any int32* into a string representing the Unicode point, but only values in the defined Unicode range:

> **Exceptions** ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>
> utf32 is *not a valid 21-bit Unicode code point* ranging from U+0
> through U+10FFFF, excluding the surrogate pair range from U+D800
> through U+DFFF.

Also, it's not clear what `d` is, and where it comes from.